# how to access a string using a variable in c#

Tags: c#

I will do my best to explain the question .
Now , for example , i have 3 public strings :

```
string a ;
string b ;
string c ;
```

i have a class which takes 1 parameter  :

```
    public void MyMethod(string variable_name)
{

}
```

Now , the variable_name will have the one of the three above string names (a or b or c) .
I Want to access these variables based on the passed value through parameter .
i can do that for textboxes using something like this :

```
 TextBox status_ = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find(variable_name, true)[0];
```

but for strings , how to do so .

hope that i was able to explain my question .

Comment: You could use reflection for this, but that's probably overkill since you know the fields ahead of time. Have you tried just add a switch or if statement to detect the value, and choose which variable you use depending on that?

Answer (score 4):

Don't.  Use the right data structure for the job.  In this case you're looking for something like a `Dictionary<string, string>`.  For example:

```
Dictionary<string, string> myVars = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "a", "" },
        { "b", "" },
        { "v", "" }
    };
```

Wherever/however you populate these values, you can do so by modifying their dictionary entries.  To fetch the falue for a given `variable_name` you would use that as your indexer:

```
myVars[variable_name]
```

Pretty much any time you have a bunch of variables with consecutive names that you want to be able to iterate or access dynamically, what you want is a collection object of some kind.